# How to fix undefined symbol error for Digikam on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, shared-library, digikam

I have upgraded a number of computers from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. After the update, I cannot run DigiKam on one of them. I tried to remove, purge and reinstall digikam,  libgdal, and libblosc1 - without success.DigiKam stops before opening any window or even the splash screen.

```
$ digikam
digikam: symbol lookup error: /lib/libgdal.so.30: undefined symbol: blosc_cbuffer_validate
$
```

I tried to find that symbol (`blosc_cbuffer_validate`) in libgdal. The symbol is undefined in the library, indeed, but that is equally the case on my other computers where digikam starts normally.

```
$ nm -gD /lib/libgdal.so.30 | grep blosc_cbuffer
                 U blosc_cbuffer_validate 
$
```

I was wondering in what way the computer that cannot run DigiKam anymore is different from the others, and can only think of these two differences:

- DigiKam was installed before the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04
- It has an AMD Ryzen CPU, whereas the others have Intel i7.

What may be the problem? How can I solve it?
Short of a solution, how could I narrow it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in **libblosc1**.

```
$ sudo apt install libblosc1
```

And verify with:

```
$ nm -gD /usr/lib/libblosc.so.1 | grep blosc_cbuffer
0000000000004580 T blosc_cbuffer_complib
0000000000004530 T blosc_cbuffer_metainfo
0000000000004440 T blosc_cbuffer_sizes
00000000000044b0 T blosc_cbuffer_validate
0000000000004570 T blosc_cbuffer_versions
```

**UPDATE**: Please provide the output of `$ ldd digikam`

**UPDATE**: It is loading the wrong file from `/opt` which can be fixed with:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblosc.so.1 digikam
```

Or by changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or by removing the version in `/opt`.

Comment: I had libblosc1 already installed. Yes, the symbol exists, but that does not impress Digikam. Location is different from yours: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblosc.so.1. Are you on Ubuntu 22.04 and x86_64?

Comment: @bogl try: `$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblosc.so.1 digikam` and provide the output of `$ ldd digikam` please.

Comment: It starts when pre-loading libblosc.so.1 !

Comment: I hesitate to provide all 413 lines of 'ldd digikam', but the location libblosc seems odd:  libblosc.so.1 => /opt/lib/blosc/lib/libblosc.so.1 (0x00007f1b34066000)

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, will do if nobody comes up with a better solution or explanation rather than a workaround.

Comment: Removing the version in `/opt` will straight up fix it.

Comment: I cannot just remove /opt/lib/blosc/ without knowing what other applications might depend on that version. It would also be worthwhile to know what caused this glitch in the first place.

Comment: @bogl Your bounty expires today.

Comment: Could you remove your request for more info on your answer (instead of using comments)? Could be useful more info about `nd`, `ldd` and the reasons behind your answer, to help others to find solutions to similar problems. @bogl `dpkg --search /opt/lib/blosc/lib/libblosc.so.1` will search for deb packages using that file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @PabloBianchi, but no deb pkg seems to rely on it. I have quite a few applications that are installed in /opt. I assume that one of these installed libblosc there.